# Linq Include statement returns an iCollection, which I cannot bind to Gridview Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, telerik

At first I used the join statement to get unique items that I could bind to my Telerik Gridview:-

```
var result = ctx.Offenders
                .Join(ctx.Fees, o => o.OffenderId, f => f.OffenderId,
                (o, f) => new { Offenders = o, Fees = f })
                .Join(ctx.ViolationOffenders, o => o.Offenders.OffenderId, vo => vo.OffenderId,
                (o, vo) => new { Offenders = o, ViolationOffenders = vo })
                .Join(ctx.Violations, v => v.ViolationOffenders.ViolationId, vo => vo.ViolationId,
                (v, vo) => new { Violations = v, ViolationOffenders = vo }).ToList();
```

This worked like a charm. However I wanted to learn a bit more about linq and the include statement. So I developed a new query:-

```
var result = ctx.Offenders
                    .Include(o => o.Fees)
                    .Include(o => o.ViolationOffenders)
                    .Include(o => o.ViolationOffenders.Select(of => of.Violation))
                    .Where(o => o.YouthNumber != "" && o.FirstName != "" && o.Fees.Any(f => f.Amount != null))
                    .ToList();

gvwData.DataSource = result;
```

I am happy with how much more compact my linq statement has turned out to be. But I am having issues binding the results to my Telerik Gridview.

The telerik Grid has columns:-

```
<Columns>
    <telerik:GridNumericColumn DataField = "YouthNumber" HeaderText="Offender ID" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" FilterControlWidth="50px" ColumnGroupName="GeneralInfo"/>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression ="LastName" DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" ColumnGroupName="GeneralInfo">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" ColumnGroupName="GeneralInfo"/>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DateOfBirth" HeaderText="DOB" ColumnGroupName="GeneralInfo"/>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PoliceReportDate" HeaderText="Report Date" ColumnGroupName="GeneralInfo"/>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Payment Owed" ColumnGroupName="BillingInfo"/>
</Columns>
```

The first 4 columns are first level data items in my variable result and they get bound to my Grid without any issues. However PoliceReportDate and Amount are returned as an iCollection....aka they are basically an array [] and not unique values for each individual gridRow as returned by my previous Linq statement.

I am trying to figure out how I can still use my 2nd linq statement and be able to bind to my Grid. I am trying to learn all possibilities with linq and entity framework.

Comment: Joining isn't a way of getting unique items (unless the columns you need to determine uniqueness are in the joined tables).  Also, if your query is returning collections for things like PoliceReportDate, then it means your data is not flat.  Flatten your data before binding it to the grid.  Also, including the structure of your database would be necessary to help you find the correct answer because there is no way for us to determine why PoliceReportDate (which sounds like it would be one value for each police report and not a column on Offenders) is a collection and not a static value.

Comment: @AaronHawkins Ofcourse "join" doesn't itself get unique items. However it is the way I am joining that evaluates to unique items. I am joining every single violation based on a unique violation Id, which means everytime an offender, has a violation with a fees attached to it, get it. Hence the uniqueness.

Comment: @AaronHawkins A single offender, can have multiple violations, with multiple fees and police report dates... hence the conundrum.

Comment: @AaronHawkins If the database were to remain as it is now, is there a way for me to still bind to the gridview is my question.

Comment: There is a way, but in order to guide you in the right direction, I need to know what you're trying to display in the grid.  Which are you trying to display?
All violators and their fee totals;
All violations along with some violation data and their fee totals;
All violations and fees for each violator;
Something else entirely;

Comment: @AaronHawkins I am trying to display, Id (which may have multiple rows with the same ID), ReportDate (which may also have multiple rows with the same date, granted chances are less of someone getting reported more than once in a day) and the fees for a booking (which has to be unique for every row). Offenders, Violations, Fees. ViolationOffender is the bridge table between offenders and violations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're within your DataContext when this code is run, the Include statements will actually have no effect.  Their main purpose is to fully load a model that may get passed around outside of the boundaries of your DataContext.

Ivan Stoev's answer was pretty close except it doesn't include the Fees, but the idea is the same.  You will need to flatten the data so that it is equivalent to your original query which is getting a record for every fee and every violation for a specific violator.  You said that the fees should be for the specific violation and, if that is the case, then I have to assume that your db structure already includes a foreign key reference from violations to fees.

`var result = ctx.Offenders
    .Where(o => o.YouthNumber != "" && o.FirstName != "" && o.Fees.Any(f => f.Amount != null))
    .SelectMany(o => o.ViolationOffenders, (o, vo) => new { o, vo, vo.Violation })
    .SelectMany(v => v.Violation.Fees, (v, vf) => new { v, vf })
    .ToList()`

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I was trying to move away from anonymous types and get familiarized with the include statement.

Comment: You should probably look up eager loading/lazy loading.  The Include statement has more value when you want to pass a fully loaded model object out of the DataContext (usually across a physical boundary of some sort).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the two queries are not equivalent. The names your used in the first query projections are misleading - Offenders, Violations, Fees (I don't see why is this btw, it's not used anywhere) should really be called Offender and Violation because they are representing a single record, but the most important thing is that all joins in the first query are [Group Joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx).

In order to produce the same result, you don't need `.Include` calls, but something like this

```
var result = ctx.Offenders.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(o => o.YouthNumber != "" && o.FirstName != "" && o.Fees.Any(f => f.Amount != null))
    .SelectMany(o => o.ViolationOffenders, (o, vo) => new { o, vo, vo.Violation }
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I understand the two queries are not equal, hence I was trying find the equality:) Do you have good linq tutorial references for me? 

also, wondering if you could help me understand what the sql for the "include" query turns out to be and why it is different. Thanks

Comment: @Philo The most important thing with EF is to forget (almost) about joins when doing queries that project fields (i.e. like sql select table1.Col1, table2.Col2 etc). `Include` is intended to be used when you want to load a whole entities (and the entities they refrence) into a db context (cache and track them). Most of the time you don't need that.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I appreciate the feedback.